# Data not storing in database for choice field for UserRegsitrationForm django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have extended the UserCreationForm of Django to add extra fields : Email and Choice field. Now when I am filling those details in the registration form and submitting it. Only the email is stored in the database and not the choice field(i.e status in the code). However when I am viewing the fields of my form in the console the choice field is showing.
But when I am accessing the attribute using the django shell I am getting an error

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users = User.objects.all()
users[6].email
Output : masterhimanshupoddar@gmail.com # success

users[6].status
Error: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c9d2701fa919> in <module>()
----> 1 users[6].status

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'status'
```

Here is my **forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, ("CEO")),
        (2, ("Dev Manager")),
        (3, ("Testing Manager")),
        (4, ("Developer")),
        (5, ("Test Engineer"))
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                         label='Email',
                         error_messages={'exists': 'Oops'})
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, label="Designation", initial='Developer', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2", "status")

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            user.status = self.cleaned_data["status"]
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

Why am I getting error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to add the field to your form, you also have to add it to the model.

For that, you need to create a custom user class in your `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("CEO")),
    (2, ("Dev Manager")),
    (3, ("Testing Manager")),
    (4, ("Developer")),
    (5, ("Test Engineer"))
)
class User(AbstractUser):
    status forms.ChoiceField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name ="Designation")
```

Then you have to change the settings `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to point to your model accordingly. Assuming the app which contains your new custom user model is called `my_app`, the setting would look like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.User'
```

You also have to make sure that any `ForeignKey` fields in your model use `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`:

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Also don't forget to create and apply database migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Unfortunately, changing the user model mid-project can lead to tricky problems, so if you are still early in your project, it might be easiest to delete and recreate your database.

Refer to your model with `get_user_model()` in your form:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
```

Please refer to the documentation on [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: what do i need to edit in settings, I am a beginner so pardon me if i am asking any silly question

Comment: I've expanded my answer, I hope that helps

Comment: why is email working but not choice field. I am unable to fix it